# Retrieve a single entity from azure table

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am trying to get a single entity from azure table using Patitionkey and Rowkey. Problem I am facing here is that, it is not returning null when no entity has matching Partitionkey or Rowkey.

```
MyRecordsTable specificEntity =
            (from e in serviceContext.CreateQuery<MyRecordsTable >("MyRecordsTable ")
             where e.PartitionKey == pkey && e.RowKey == rkey
             select e).FirstOrDefault();
```

I referred following link, it says if no matching, then null should be returned. But I am getting a exception (`An error occurred while processing this request.`) Internal exception is `No resource found.`

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/#header-11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is default behavior for any REST driven data source. If it is not found, a HTTP 404 error is returned. If you want to get NULL instead, you have to use the [IgnoreResourceNotFoundException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.ignoreresourcenotfoundexception.aspx) property and set it to true.